# Vue.js and Firebase - return query based on route param

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vue-router, vuefire

I'm working on something in Vue.js where I need to pass a value (symbol) that is coming from vue-router into a Firebase database query to retrieve the JSON object that matches that query. I can only do this via a v-for / v-if hack within the template. I know there must be a way to simply return this query within my script tags.

I have access to the database via the vuefire plugin.

```
  <template>
  <div>
    <h3>Edit Crypto</h3>
    <div v-for="crypto in getCryptos" :key="crypto[symbol]">
      <div v-if="crypto.symbol === symbol">
      {{ crypto.name }} - {{ crypto.symbol }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      {{ cryptoTest }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**dbCryptosRef** is the database (image below) reference. **getCrypto** is the method I am trying to use to query the dabase. Below is the script tag within the same file. **dbCryptosRef.equalTo(this.$route.params.symbol)** simply returns the url for the firebase database, not as JSON object. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import { dbCryptosRef } from '../firebaseConfig'

export default {
  data()
    {
      return {
        symbol: this.$route.params.symbol,
        crypto: {},
        cryptoTest: {}
      }
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters ([
        'getCryptos'
      ])
    },
    methods: {
      getCrypto: function()
      {
        this.cryptoTest = dbCryptosRef.equalTo(this.$route.params.symbol)
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.getCrypto();
    }
}
</script>
```

[image: Firebase database]

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `value` to get the data

```
getCrypto: function() {
 this.cryptoTest = dbCryptosRef.equalTo(this.$route.params.symbol).once('value').then(snapshot => {
  // do what you want with snapshot data
 })
}
```

You can read more in [Firebase document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)